# Nancy doesn't render Model data on the view (VB.NET)

Tags: nancy

My application is a Console App (VB.Net) which uses Self-hosted Nancy (with TopShelf).

I can return html Views perfectly, but I'm not able to return a view that uses a model correctly .. the html page just display @Model.whatever without replacing it.

Here's my code:

In NancyModule:

```
        [Get]("dashboard/blank") = Function()

                                   Dim SimpleClass = New SimpleClass With {
                                            .Name = "John",
                                            .Any = "Smith"
                                        }

                                   Return View("webserver/dashboard/views/blank.html", SimpleClass)

                               End Function
```

The Model:

```
   Public Class SimpleClass
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Any As String
    End Class
```

The html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Blank</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Display @SimpleClass.Name</h1>
    <h1>Display @SimpleClass.Any</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the disappointing output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made a mistake in the html page ... Nancy will only replace the keyword "Model" (Case-sensitive) not any name ..